# Sum and product of two transcendental numbers can't be both algebraic

Tags: abstract-algebra, transcendental-numbers

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers and both transcendental over $\mathbb Q$. I am wondering why $ab$ and $a+b$ can not both be algebraic.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $x^2-(a+b)x+ab=(x-a)(x-b)$. (and the set of algebraic numbers is an algebraically closed field.)

Comment: Do you mean real ?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/899097/sum-and-product-of-two-transcendental-numbers-cannot-be-simultaneously-algebraic

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Suppose $s=a+b$ and $p=ab$ are both algebraic numbers. Then,

$$p=ab=a(s-a)=sa-a^2,$$

IOW, $a$ is the root of a second degree polynomial with algebraic coefficients.